# C++ templates that use external functions

Tags: c++, templates, external

does C++ allow using external functions in template specification implementations? What I wanna do is make a wrapper to BLAS/LAPACK (the CBLAS doesn't cut it for me, I need a couple of functions that are not in there and are in the external BLAS), somewhat like this

```
extern "C" {
    void saxpy_(int* n, const float* const sa, const float* const sx, int* incx, float* sy, int* incy);
    void daxpy_(int* n, const double* const sa, const double* const sx, int* incx, double* sy, int* incy);
}
namespace matrix {
template<class T>
void ax_plus_y(const T a, const Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>& x, Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>& y) {
    y += a * x;
}

template<>
void ax_plus_y<float>(const float a, const Matrix<float, Dynamic, 1>& x, Matrix<float, Dynamic, 1>& y) {
    int n = x.size();
    int incx = x.innerStride();
    int incy = y.innerStride();
    saxpy_(&n, &a, x.data, &incx, y.data(), &incy);
}

template<>
void ax_plus_y<double>(const double a, const Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>& x, Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>& y) {
    int n = x.size();
    int incx = x.innerStride();
    int incy = y.innerStride();
    daxpy_(&n, &a, x.data, &incx, y.data(), &incy);
}
}
```

That's just a snippet of what I need, but is this possible at all? I can't really use only one function, 'cause I need the different external calls for each data type.

P.S. The `Matrix` is from Eigen, shouldn't be relevant to concept.

EDIT: To clarify, this is what g++ throws up with:

```
error: template-id ‘ax_plus_y<float>’ for ‘void matrix::ax_plus_y(float, const Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, 1>&, Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, 1>&)’ does not match any template declaration
```

Comment: We used an old compiler that would create classes for each combination used in a template, which would probably work for what you're trying to do.  Newer or more dynamic compilers, no idea.  What happens when you try it with yours?

Comment: What are `Matrix` and `Dynamic`?

Comment: I wrote that at end of the post, they're both from Eigen.

Comment: That error message confirms my answer. `Dynamic` is apparently a constant equal to `-1ul`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you declare three things:

```
template<class T>
void ax_plus_y(const T a, const Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>& x, 
    Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>& y);

template<>
void ax_plus_y<float>(const float a, const Matrix<float, Dynamic, 1>& x, 
    Matrix<float, Dynamic, 1>& y);

template<>
void ax_plus_y<double>(const double a, const Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>& x, 
     Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>& y);
```

The function signatures of the specializations, which use `Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1>`, do not match the general function signature, which uses `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>`, so the compiler will not associate the specializations with the general template. I don't think that the compiler is going to jump through implicit-typecast hoops to make this work for you.

**EDIT:** As to your general "is it possible" question: Yes, but it's going to take a lot of effort, and you might want to consider writing some kind of code-generating program to keep you from going insane.

I've done this years ago, but not with `Matrix` or `Vector` classes, just with `const T*, size_t` pairs. My goal was legibility (BLAS/LAPACK function names are more about brevity than clarity), support for other libraries such as FFTW and SSE, and support for types outside those packages. The idea was that you'd use the general routines and it would generate the best code for your platform. Unfortunately, I can't open-source it and it's a decade out of support.

In your case, you're going to have to write something like:

```
template<class T, long long D1=Dynamic, long long D2=Dynamic>
void ax_plus_y(const T a, const Matrix<T, D1, D2>& x, Matrix<T, D1, D2>& y) {
    y += a * x;
}

template<long long D1=Dynamic>
void ax_plus_y<float, D1, 1>(const float a, const Matrix<float, D1, 1>& x, Matrix<float, D1, 1>& y) {
    int n = x.size();
    int incx = x.innerStride();
    int incy = y.innerStride();
    saxpy_(&n, &a, x.data, &incx, y.data(), &incy);
}

template<long long D2=Dynamic>
void ax_plus_y<float, 1, D2>(const float a, const Matrix<float, 1, D2>& x, Matrix<float, 1, D2>& y) {
    int n = x.size();
    int incx = x.outerStride();
    int incy = y.outerStride();
    saxpy_(&n, &a, x.data, &incx, y.data(), &incy);
}
```

and repeat for `double`.

Comment: Great edit, I don't think I'm gonna need the generator just yet, and I keep the Eigen stuff around for higher level things (like accessing members via the overloaded operator() etc.) and use this for the lower stuff that is really performance critical and uses MKL.

Comment: Ah, I remember MKL. Supporting it was the last thing I did with my library.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Well for one, afaik templates are translated @ compile time, not compiled, wouldn't the call to that external need to get compiled? Plus, I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Templates *are* compiled at compile time. There's no intermediate "template store" where they go. That's why it's encouraged to put templates in header files.

Comment: @TC1: Er, what? If you have problems, then post a question about those problems, not imagined ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with extern functions in template functions. See e.g. the following snippet that works fine:

http://codepad.org/lF8AKwPV :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

template<typename T>
void doit(T number)
{
   std::cout << cos(number) << std::endl;
}

template<>
void doit<float>(float number)
{
   std::cout << "a float: " << cos(number) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  doit((double)0.0);
  doit((float)1.0);
}
```

Maybe it's a problem that the first template defintion is in namespace "matrix" while the others aren't?